# Posts list page, Django Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I am making a news site, there is a page where all articles are displayed. But if there are many articles, then the page will be huge.

[image: what is now]

my code :

```
{%  block content %}
    
    <div class=" container" style="margin-top: 60px;">
    
        {% for post in posts %}
            <div class="row" style="padding-top: 30px ">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    {% image post.preview_image fill-250x250 as blog_img %}

                    <img style="border-radius: .3525rem" href="{{ post.url }}" src="{{ blog_img.url }}">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <a href="{{ post.url }}">
                        {{ post.title }}
                    </a>
                    <br/>
                    <p> {{ post.intro }}</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        {% endfor %}


    </div>
{% endblock content  %}
```

what i want to do
[image: what i want to do]

Comment: Check out the Django docs on pagination:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using pagination   : https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/how-to-paginate-your-wagtail-pages/

Comment: This is not how SO should be used. You can post an answer to your own question if no satisfactory answer has been provided. But this is not an answer to a problem, it is a pointer to the basic concept of pagination, which doesn't make for a good answer (and was already suggested by someone else in a comment).